# Image Sitemap & Duplicate Content

Tags: sitemap, duplicate-content, xml-sitemap

I made an Image sitemap with Udinra All Image Sitemap plugin:

[image: Image_Sitemap]

As you see, there are a lot of fields in the right side that have page URLs, And I already have them in my main sitemap. Does this count as duplicated content by google? I mean, I wanna submit this to google webmaster tools & I don't want any negative impact on my website. Any help is appreciated

P.S: Do I need to put image title & caption in sitemap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sitemap is taken as a **suggestion** of what to crawl by Google. Don't be too shy to throw everything at the wall to see what sticks.

If you have duplicate URLs in your sitemaps, Google will raise these as an error in your Search Console and ignore them.